# I need to type cast my list_of_list to floats

Tags: python

I cannot seem to type cast my list_of_list to a float no matter what I try. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can get my labels list to convert to an int or float but not my list_of_list.

```
def build_list(data):

list_of_lists = []
label = []
subLab = []
sub1 = []
labels = []
sub = []
list_of_l = []
list_of_l = data.tolist()


[float(i) for i in list_of_l]
    

for x in range(len(list_of_l)):
    if(x != 0):
        sub = list_of_l[x]
        
        for i in range(len(sub)):
            subLab = list_of_l[x][-1]
            sub1 = list_of_l[x][:-1]
        labels.append(int(subLab))
        list_of_lists.append(sub1)
        print(type(labels))
        print(type(list_of_lists))
#[ for i in list_of_lists]

return(list_of_lists, labels)
```

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect, this code will not run as written. Please confirm that your indentation is showing the same way as in your IDE, so it is clear what your code is doing. You can paste your code into the text box and wrap it with triple backticks to preserve formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You created the new list here:

```
[float(i) for i in list_of_l]
```

but you didn't do anything with it.

Do:

```
list_of_l = [float(i) for i in list_of_l]
```

if you want to replace `list_of_l` with your new list of floats.